# Couldn't run rails server! gem 'rails x86-mingw32' not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run rails server and this error comes up!

[Error message on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odETG.png)

Gemfile

gem 'Rails', '4.2.6'

gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

Comment: Have you `bundle install`ed?

Comment: I've tried that (bundle install)!

Comment: try: gem install rails 4.2.6 and then bundle update rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors

[Could not find gem 'rails x86-mingw32'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520419/could-not-find-gem-rails-x86-mingw32)

And try deleting the `Gemfile.lock`, then `bundle install`ing again.

Comment: I still have the same problem!

Comment: Hmm, has Rails ever worked on your machine? It looks to me like your running on Windows. Try deleting the `Gemfile.lock`, then `bundle install`-ing again.

Comment: Finally! worked like charm following this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows). Thanks a lot @fbelanger